# Insert into a class only selected from a customlistive with checkboxes

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I'm using this a custom listview with checkboxes inside.

How can i take the name of each row where checkbox is checked and add it into a class?

Here is my my code:

```
 SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ExtrasPreviewMain);
        OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Layout.trans_left_in, Resource.Layout.trans_left_out);
        var BackBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExtrasBackButton);
        var AcceptBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExtrasAcceptButton);
        AcceptBtn.Click += AcceptBtn_Click;



        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name from InventoryMaster where MainGroupItemID=" + Connection.CategoryID + "", con);

        mlistview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ExtrasList);
        mItems = new List<ExtrasPreviewClass>();
        SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            mItems.Add(new ExtrasPreviewClass() { ExtrasName = sqlReader["Name"].ToString() });


        }
        MyListViewAdapterExtras adapter = new MyListViewAdapterExtras(this, mItems);
        mlistview.Adapter = adapter;
        sqlReader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }

    private void AcceptBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checkbox = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasCheckBox);
        var name = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasName);


           foreach (var item in mItems)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(item.ExtrasCheckBox)== true)
            {
                Connection.Extras = Connection.Extras + item.ExtrasName + ",";
            }
        }
```

But it doesnt shows me anything in my last result
Example if will have

Extras      checkbox
Sugar       checked
milk        checked

My result will be empty

And this is my adapter code:

```
  class MyListViewAdapterExtras : BaseAdapter<ExtrasPreviewClass>
{
    public List<ExtrasPreviewClass> mitems;
    private Context mContext;
    public MyListViewAdapterExtras(Context context, List<ExtrasPreviewClass> items)
    {
        mitems = items;
        mContext = context;

    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems.Count;
        }
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override ExtrasPreviewClass this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems[position];
        }

    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ExtrasPreview, null, false);

        }



        TextView txtExtrasName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasName);
        txtExtrasName.Text = mitems[position].ExtrasName;
        CheckBox txtExtrasCheckBox = row.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasCheckBox);
        txtExtrasCheckBox.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].ExtrasCheckBox);



        return row;
    }
```

And my class

```
class ExtrasPreviewClass
{
    public string ExtrasName { get; set; }
    public CheckBox ExtrasCheckBox { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the GetView method from your Adapter, you will have to set an Tag for the CheckBox, with the item information, and register an EventListener for when the CheckBox is CheckedChanged, like this:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //Prepare convertView here
    CheckBox itemCheckBox = convertView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.itemCheckBox);
    if(itemCheckBox.Tag == null)
        itemCheckBox.Tag = new Java.Lang.String(this.items[position].name); //set the checkbox tag with information about your item. The tag object class must inherit from Java.Lang.Object
    itemCheckBox.CheckedChange -= itemCheckBox_CheckedChange; //this is to avoid registering the event more than once when scrolling the listview
    itemCheckBox.CheckedChange += itemCheckBox_CheckedChange;
    return convertView;
}

private void itemCheckBox_CheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    // Java.Lang.Object myTag = myCheckBox.Tag;
    // String itemName = ((Java.Lang.String)myTag).ToString();
    //save in a variable that your item was checked
    //for example:
    // foreach(Item i in this.items)
    // {
    //     if(i.name.Equals(itemName))
    //     {
    //         i.IsChecked = myCheckBox.Checked;
    //         break;
    //     }
    // }
}
```